# Invalid HAAR feature (expected: 'rw.r.x + rw.r.width <= W')

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pycharm

I am trying to load a classifier, but it shows an error:

```
 Invalid HAAR feature (expected: 'rw.r.x + rw.r.width <= W'), where
     'rw.r.x + rw.r.width' is 22
 must be less than or equal to
     'W' is 16
```

Python and XML file both are in the same directory.